# Porque TypeError ocorre?

Tags: javascript

### Olá, estou estudando javascript e realizando alguns testes e gostaria de entender por que essa forma de chamada gera erro.

```
function test (){
    function printA(){
        console.log("a");
    }
}
test.printA();

Uncaught TypeError: test.printA is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:6
```

---

```
function test (){
        function printA(){
            console.log("a");
        }
        printA();
    }
test();
a
```

Comment: Oi Luiz! Dá uma olhada a essas outras perguntas. Se ainda tiveres duvidas esclarece melhor aqui para respondermos.

Comment: Achei que fosse mesmo algo relacionado ao escopo, mas não sabia como explicar. Poderia ver se minha compreensão esta correta?  A função "printA" esta no escopo local  de "test", portanto só pode ser acessada através de "test" ou atribuído-a  a um objeto, correto?

Comment: Exato! funções e variáveis declaradas dentro do escopo de uma função não são acessíveis fora.